# Node.js fs.readFile vs jQuery $.getJSON - which is faster?

Tags: jquery, json, performance, node.js, node-webkit

I'm working on a program running in Node-Webkit, and I use jQuery for many other tasks. Now I have a settings.json file that I need to load upon the start of the program, and I was thinking about how to load it.

So either I use the node.js fs functions to read the data from the file and then use JSON.parse to get the correct data in a javascript object, or I use the jQuery fnuction $.getJSON which in one function gets the json file, parses it and returns a data object.

Now I was wondering, is there data on the speed of both? Would the jQuery option be significantly slower if the settings.json file were to get larger (e.g. when I add more settings) or is the difference negligible? I'm assuming here that the jQuery way would be slower than the node.js way, since it would seem logical to me that an operation on the filesystem would be faster than a jQuery get request, but then again I could be wrong.

Anyone who can help me out with some information on this? I have to add that I'm fairly new to node.js, I understand what it does but I've only been trying it out for about a week now so I haven't done any substantial reading or research on any of it.

Comment: better solution: use `require('./settings.json')`

Comment: Will that also give me the javascript object from the json code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the require function to do this at once.

```
var settings = require('path/to/settings.json');
// settings is your JSON parsed object
```

To your real question, `FS module` is going to be as fast or faster than jQuery.getJSON because in the best case scenario, if jQuery.getJSON even actually works in loading a local file, jQuery.getJSON will have boiler plate code which at the end will use the Node's core FS module. More likely, jQuery.getJSON might only work for HTTP protocol request (haven't looked at the nodejs port) whereas you are trying to load a local file.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the require function could be used in this way.

Comment: Also, jQuery's getJSON (and in fact all ajax functions) seem to work just fine within Node-Webkit, so far I haven't had any problem using them.